# using regular expression in Java

Tags: java, regex

i need to check a string that should contain only ABCDEFG characters, in any sequence and with  only 7 characters. Please let me know the correct way of using regular expression.

as corrently i am using

```
String abs = "ABPID";
if(!Pattern.matches("[[ABCDEFG]", abs))
System.out.println("Error");
```

i am using the following code which works when i use the String abcdefg but for other cases it fails. please help me out.

Comment: How about duplicates? Is "AAAAAAA" also acceptable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To see if a string is a permutation of `ABCDEFG`, it's easy with negative lookahead and capturing group to enforce no duplicates:

```
^(?!.*(.).*\1)[A-G]{7}$
```

You don't need the anchors if you use `String.matches()` in Java. Here's a test harness:

```
    String[] tests = {
        "ABCDEFG", // true
        "GBADFEC", // true
        "ABCADFG", // false
    };
    for (String test : tests) {
        System.out.format("%s %b%n", test,
            test.matches("(?!.*(.).*\\1)[A-G]{7}")
        );
    }
```

Basically, `[A-G]{7}`, but also `(?!.*(.).*\1)`. That is, no character is repeated.

Here's a test harness for the assertion to play around with:

```
    String[] tests = {
        "abcdeb", // "(b)"
        "abcdefg", // "abcdefg"
        "aba", // "(a)"
        "abcdefgxxxhijyyy" // "(y)"
    };
    for (String test : tests) {
        System.out.println(test.replaceAll("(?=.*(.).*\\1).*", "($1)"));
    }
```

The way it works is by trying to match `.*(.).*\1`, that is, with `.*` in between, a captured character `(.)` that appears again `\1`.

#### See also

- [regular-expressions.info/Lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: +1, very nice.  still, that uniqueness syntax...that has to be memorized.

Comment: @Carl: nope, it's very intuitive. You want to capture `(.)`, and use backreferences to see if it appears again `\1`. You want to allow these two occurrences to be separated by `.*`. It's understandable, it doesn't have to be memorized.

Answer (score 6):

Exactly 7 characters

```
"^[ABCDEFG]{7}$"
```

1 to 7 characters

```
"^[ABCDEFG]{1,7}$"
```

Comment: (Not quite serious as it's obviously not what the OP meant, but) you can even enforce "exactly 7 characters, no duplicates, in any order": `^(?:A()|B()|C()|D()|E()|F()|G()){7}\1\2\3\4\5\6\7$`

Comment: Adding to the above problem, if i need that one character should come only once, then what will be the expression???? please help..

Comment: if i need duplicates in the string.. i tried the above one but it is not working.. please help

Comment: @Mrityunjay, Please take a look Tim's comment for that, and Thanks Tim

Comment: Probably `"^(?:A()|B()|C()|D()|E()|F()|G()){7}\\1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6\\7$"` in java, for once char once